# Create an Spring Boot Executable jar AND a regular library jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I have a regular Java project that creates a jar file that is a library of stuff that is used in a webapp. It's a Spring Boot starter that creates a jar.  Simple stuff.

I wanted to be able to run this as a stand alone executable jar file.  So I write a standard Application.java that implements CommandLineRunner and I add this to my plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

and presto,  my jar is executable.

However,  that plugin changes the directory structure such that it is no longer a regular library jar,  and my webapplication fails to find the classes in it.  When I remove the plugin entry in my pom,  the webapp works fine,  but the jar is no longer executable.

Is it possible to do both? And if so, how?

Comment: The right approach is to move the common stuff into separate maven project and reference it in both Spring Boot and you web app. Alternatively you can use maven assembly plugin to generate second jar artifact.

Answer (score 1):

It was possible prior to Spring Boot 1.4.1, but not since.  1.4.1 changed the directory structure in an executable jar.  for 1.4.1 and after, a jar can be executable or a library but not both.

If you really need the same jar to be both executable and a library, you'll need to revert to Spring Boot 1.4.0 or earlier.